# How to get all indices of all chars in the list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary that takes a char in a list as key, the value should be a new list containing the indices on which the char occurs.

Something like:
list = [„a“,“b“,“a“,“d“]
Should return
{„a“: [0,2], „b“: [0], „d“: [3]}

I dont have a problem with writing a comprehension that returns a list of the indices of a specific character, for example „a“.

```
def idx(chars):
    d = {}
    l = [i for i,x in enumerate(chars) if x == "a"]
    for c in chars:
        d[c] = l
        return d

            
        
print(idx(["a","b","c", "a", "z", "v"]))
```

But how do i generalize it to iterate over all chars and get their indices?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the pairs `(index, element)` and append the index to the key corresponding to the element.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> l = ["a","b","a", "d"]
>>> res = defaultdict(list)
>>> for idx, el in enumerate(l):
...     res[el].append(idx)
... 
>>> res
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [0, 2], 'b': [1], 'd': [3]})
```